# Showing undefined along with the string when iterating object

Tags: javascript, arrays

When i tried to iterate object and i want to convert it into a string to append the URL, but undefined is showing along with the string?

This is my function to convert object to string

```
onFormattedFilterChange(urlParams) {
    let formattedParams;
    Object.keys(urlParams).forEach((item, i) => {
      formattedParams += '&' + item + '=' + urlParams[item];
    });
  }
```

Where my urlParams

```
{projectType: "FP", status: "COMPLETE", code: "SG", executionType: "INTERNAL"}
```

I want  string in the form of

```
&projectType=FP&status=COMPLETE&code=SG&executionType=INTERNAL
```

But instead of this it is showing

```
undefined&projectType=FP&status=COMPLETE&code=SG&executionType=INTERNAL
```

Why it showing undefined?

Comment: Typo type: `let formattedParams = "";`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to initialise the formattedParams as I mentioned in my comment.

But I suggest you use the built-in URLSearchParams

```js
const urlParams = {"projectType": "FP", "status": "COMPLETE", "code": "SG", "executionType": "INTERNAL"} 

var formattedParams= new URLSearchParams();
for (key in urlParams) {
  formattedParams.append(key, urlParams[key]);
}
console.log(formattedParams.toString())
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not initialized formattedParams hence it is undefined which is getting concatenated later in forEach.Initializing it as an empty string solves it.

```
function onFormattedFilterChange(urlParams) {
    let formattedParams="";
    Object.keys(urlParams).forEach((item, i) => {
      formattedParams += '&' + item + '=' + urlParams[item];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with `let formattedParams;`. You need to initialise

```
onFormattedFilterChange(urlParams) {
  let formattedParams = '';
  Object.keys(urlParams).forEach((item, i) => {
    formattedParams += '&' + item + '=' + urlParams[item];
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You declare a variable formattedParams, which is undefined, then you add to it other params inside the loop. You can assign an empty string to your declaration to fix this issue.